# Laravel registration route doesn't work with localization package

Tags: php, laravel

I use this package for localization https://github.com/mcamara/laravel-localization ...

And I have set `'hideDefaultLocaleInURL'  => true,`. My default locale is German, so when I enter registration page the URL is `http://localhost:8000/register` and everything works fine. But if user selects English language (`http://localhost:8000/en/register`) it doesn't register the user, it just redirects back to register form.

I think something is wrong with register route definition. Is there a way to fix this?

This is my route list for registration:

```
 POST - register - App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController@register
 GET - register 
 App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController@showRegistrationForm
```

and middlewares from localization package are applied on these routes:

```
web,localeSessionRedirect,localizat
ionRedirect,guest
```

Answer (score 0):

I have this and it works fine for me. Try my routes setup;

```
<?php
Route::group(
    [
        'prefix' => LaravelLocalization::setLocale(),
        'middleware' => ['localize', 'localeSessionRedirect', 'localizationRedirect', 'localeViewPath' ]
    ],
    function()
    {
        /**
         * Auth and login routes
         */
        // Authentication Routes...
        Auth::routes();
    }
);
```

Comment: I have the same setup. But the problem is with language prefix in register route. `/en/register`, `/de/register`. These doesn't work. `/register`, this works...

Comment: I have tested my version and when no local/local is the default all works fine and the url does not have the local. When I choose another locale it works and the local is in the url.   Do you have 'locale', 'locales', and 'fallback_locale' set in your main config, the right 'supportedLocales' set in your laravellocaliztion config?

Comment: If all is set, have you tried clearing all the caches?

Comment: Where can I check for 'locale', 'locales', and 'fallback_locale'?

Comment: mine is set is `config/app.php`; approx lines 80->94

Comment: It is set...  `'locale'          => 'de, 'fallback_locale' => 'en',`

Answer (score 0):

this question is fairly old but I encountered the same problem with Laravel 7. I somehow solved the issue by adding a line in the middleware handle(), if anyone is still having the same issue.

```
URL::defaults(['locale' => $request->segment(1)]);
```